# Faster R-CNN / Mask R-CNN: is it possible to fix the number of instances?

Tags: faster-rcnn

Is it possible to get a fixed number of boxes/instances from Faster/Mask R-CNN algorithms?

I am using Mask R-CNN to segment 5 layers in a retina OCT image. But it only produces 2-3 layers, even though all the input images in the training set have 5 layers annotated.

Is there a way to force a fixed number of instances?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Detectron2 library to run Faster/Mask R-CNN.
One can set a maximum for the number of detected objects by setting the parameter `NMS_THRESH_TEST`. However, there is no way to put a lower bound for the number of detected objects. One can only fine tune this parameter `SCORE_THRESH_TEST` to get more objects detected though.